# Video editing software for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, video, software-rec, editing

What are the best recommendations in video editing software for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iMovie at the low end, and Final Cut Pro at the high end.

Comment: Final Cut Express right in the middle ;-)