# Video Editing Application for Mac

Tags: macos, video-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video editing software for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/150941/video-editing-software-for-mac-os-x)

Hi,

Which video editor application for Mac OS X would you recommend to add special effects to existing video. This is for a teen so we need any easy to learn application.

Answer (score 1):

iMovie is the intro-level movie editor, and comes with every Mac, but it's not incredibly powerful. Final Cut Express is probably the best balance between power and ease of use (although it does have a bit of a learning curve).